# Getting properties from forms in IlSpy

Tags: c#, .net, ilspy

Is it possible to get the properties (width, height, location, ...) of e.g. labels, buttons, textboxes, ... in IlSpy for .Net? My problem is, I have done a project but lost the project file, so there is only the .exe-file available. And I really don't wanna redesign the whole GUI again.

Comment: Have you tried it??  It's pretty straightforward to use...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WinForms, all the generated code for the designer (width, height, location, text, ...) is placed into the `InitializeComponent` function in the respective Form class. You can decompile this method and find all the information that you need to recreate the form.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know about this. I will try it, thanks.